# Efficient lookup of a buffer with stack of data modifications applied

Tags: c++, algorithm, buffer, undo

I am trying to write a C++11 library as part of a wider project that implements a stack of changes (modification, insertion and deletion) implemented on top of an original buffer. Then, the aim is to be able to quickly look "through" the changes and get the modified data out.

My current approach is:

- Maintain an ordered list of changes, ordered by offset of the start of the change
- Also maintain a stack of the same changes, so they can be rolled back in order
- New changes are pushed onto the stack and inserted into the list at the right place
- The changes-by-offset list may be modified if the change interacts with others

  - For example, a modification of bytes 5-10 invalidates the start of an earlier modification from 8-12
  - Also, insertion or deletion changes will change the apparent offset of data occurring after them (deleting bytes 5-10 means that what used to be byte 20 is now found at 15)
- To find the modified data, you can look though the list for the change that applies (and the offset within that change that applies - another change might have invalidated some of it), or find the right offset in the original data if no change touched that offset

  - The aim here is to make the lookup fast - adding a change might take some effort to mess with the list, but lookups later, which will outnumber the modifications greatly, in an ordered list should be pretty straightforward.
  - Also you don't need to continuously copy data - each change's data is kept with it, and the original data is untouched
- Undo is then implemented by popping the last change off the stack and rolling back any changes made to it by this change's addition.

This seems to be quite a difficult task - there are a lot of things to take care of and I am quickly piling up complex code!

I feel sure that this must be problem that has been dealt with in other software, but looking around various hex editors and so on hasn't pointed me to a useful implementation. Is there a name for this problem ("data undo stack" and friends hasn't got me very far!), or a library that can be used, even as a reference, for this kind of thing?

Comment: This makes me think of https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_Darcs/Patch_theory.  darcs is a distributed version control system, like git but based on tracking collections of patches, rather than tracking snapshots of trees (like git does).  You might want to look around in the darcs source code for algorithms to efficiently get the data at a given revision.  However, I think you'll have much better results from keeping the "current state" directly, and inverting things into undo info, like 500's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most common approach (one I have used successfully in the past) is to simply store the original state and then put each change operation (what's being done + arguments) on the undo stack. Then, to get to a particular prior state you start from the original and apply all changes except the ones you want undone.

This is a lot easier to implement than trying to identify what parts of the data changed, and it works well unless the operations themselves are very time-consuming (and therefore slow to "replay" onto the original state).

Comment: Yes, this is my fallback when I fail to (or before I do) find a good way to unpick the changes - I won't have so many that this is not feasible. However, constructing the lookup in the first place is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at persistent data structures, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure and http://www.toves.org/books/persist/#s2 - or websearch on terms from these. I think you could do this with a persistent tree whose leaves carry short strings.